# How to share dynamic text in android ShareActionProvider

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, shareactionprovider

I want to share dynamic text using ShareActionProvider. I'm using this code in my Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.detailfragment, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);

    if (mForecast != null) {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareForecastIntent());
        }
}  

private Intent createShareForecastIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, editText.getText().toString());
    return shareIntent;
}
```

This will share the text that was before entering the Activity, even if I'll change it in EditText before pressing share button. And this code works as I want, but I don't want to make separate button for sharing:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                Intent myIntent = new Intent();
                myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, editText.getText().toString());
                myIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                break;
        default:
                //
    }
}
```

I'm using:

```
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 19
```

Comment: Try setting the Share Intent in your onOptionsItemSelected method

Answer (score 0):

Update your `shareIntent` when the text changes, using a `TextWatcher`. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ShareNative) has an activity that does just what you describe:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.sap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener, TextWatcher {
  private ShareActionProvider share=null;
  private Intent shareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  private EditText editor=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    editor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editor);
    editor.addTextChangedListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);

    share=
        (ShareActionProvider)menu.findItem(R.id.share)
                                 .getActionProvider();
    share.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(this);

    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source,
                                       Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(this, intent.getComponent().toString(),
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return(false);
  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, s.toString());
    share.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                int after) {
    // ignored
  }

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                            int count) {
    // ignored
  }
}
```

Note that I am not sure if the `setShareIntent()` call is needed on every text change; I haven't tried removing that and just updating the extra.

Comment: I need to share text from 2 different textviews concated to one string and I set text with the setText method, but as I understood TextWatcher doesn't accept it as changed, is there else solutions?